# Compute the reduced factors $ QR $ of $ K_{n} $ using Arnoldi iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $ A $ be a $ n \times n $ matrix and $ b $ be a $ n \times 1 $ column vector. Then I can construct the Krylov matrix $ K_{n} = [b, Ab, A^2b, \dots, A^{n - 1}b] $. I know that $ K_{n} $ has a reduced $ QR $ factorization $ K_{n} = Q_{n}R_{n} $ where $ Q_{n} $ is the $ Q_{n} $ matrix obtained from [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration). My question is how do I compute $ R_{n} $ so that $ K_{n} = Q_{n}R_{n} $? I am thinking of solving a system of $ n^2 $ equations from $ K_{n} = Q_{n}R_{n} $, but that would be impractical for large $ n $. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $m$ denote the grade of $b$ with respect $A$, i.e., the largest $m$ such that $K_m$ has full rank $m$. In exact arithmetic, the Arnoldi algorithm terminates after $m$ iterations and returns the factorization $$AV = V H,$$ where $V  = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_m \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is an orthonormal matrix with $b = \|b\|_2 v_1$, and $H \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is an upper Hessenberg matrix. Then $$A^j b = \|b\|_2 A^j V e_1 = \|b\|_2 V H^j e_1,$$ where $e_1$ is the first column vector of the identity matrix of dimension $m$. It follows, that $$K_m = \|b\|_2\,V \begin{bmatrix} e_1 & He_1 & H^2 e_1 & \dotsc & H^{m-1} e_1 \end{bmatrix} =: VR.$$
The fact that $R$ is upper triangular with positive diagonal entries follows from the fact that $H$ is upper Hessenberg with positive subdiagonal entries.

This shows that $K_m = V R$ is the $QR$ decomposition of $K_m$.

---

An early version of this answer mistakenly identified $K_m$ with $VH$.