# Solving some special linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Assuming we have some matrix $A\in \mathbb C^{m\times m}$ with $n\leq m$ of full rank and there are some vectors $q,b\in \mathbb C^m$. We are now trying to solve the following system
$$\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}  q&Aq&A^2q&\dots&A^{n-1}q   \end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\\vdots \\x_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b_1\\\vdots \\b_m \end{pmatrix},$$
while we assume that this problem is solvable. The left part looks strongly related to Krylov-subspace methods like the Arnoldi-iteration or GMRES. But this methods, as far as I understand, find the eigenvectors of $A$ or solve the system $Ax=b$ respectively. So, those methods give me information about $A$ and not  about $(q|Aq|\dots|A^{n-1}q)$. Is there some method which can solve the given equation above numerically in a stable way? I would be grateful about some tips or keywords which I can search?

Comment: "with n≤m" But where is $n$?

Comment: $n$ is appearing later in the linear system, in the "Krylov" matrix $(q|Aq|\dots|A^{n-1}q)$.

Comment: You write that $b\in\mathbb{C}^m$, but below we see that $b$ has height $n$.

Comment: You are right, I changed it into $m$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this linear system is so ill-conditioned that you will not be able to trust the computed result. This is particularly clear in the case where $A$ has dominant eigenvalue. In this case the computed values $\hat{y}_j$ of the vectors $y_j=A^j q$ will tend to point in the direction of a dominant eigenvector even when $q$ does not contain any component in this direction. This ensures that the matrix is very ill-conditioned. It is possible to obtain the orthogonal factor of the QR factorization of the Krylov matrix in question see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2273630/307944), but it is not clear to me that we can get the triangular factor in a reliable manner.